# How to exec procedure through jdbc in Syabse ase

Tags: jdbc, sybase, sap-ase

I test Sybase ASE jdbc "jconn4.jar" to exec procedure.
Such as "sp_adduser N'probe', N'test12', N'test_group'"

`CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("sp_adduser N'probe', N'test12', N'test_group'");`

Execute code:

`cstmt.executeQuery();`
OR
`cstmt.execute();`

But their are all failed.

Could Anyone help me to deal with this issue?

Thanks in advence

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you include the error messages you got -- were there any?

As a first start: try adding the EXECUTE keyword?